# What is the difference between Future.delayed vs Timer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, time, delay, future

I like to know the differences between Future.delayed and Timer method for delaying code execution. Both seem to do the same thing.

**Future.delayed**

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () { /*code*/ });
```

**VS**

**Timer**

```
Timer _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () { /*code*/ });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of differences for me.

- `Future.of` returns a Future.
- `Timer` does not return anything.

So if your *delayed code* returns anything that you need to continue your working, `Future` is the way to go.

---

Other difference is that the `Timer` class provides a way to fire repeatedly.

This quote is from the [Timer Class Reference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Timer-class.html) documentation itself

> A count-down timer that can be configured to fire once or **repeatedly**

And example to use `Timer` with the **repeat** could be

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
    print(DateTime.now()); 
});
```

Other frecuent example is to create a *stopwatch*, to measure timings in your code, it's usually seen using a `Timer`.

GL!!

Comment: Another important difference is that a `Timer` can be cancelled.  Also, for measuring time, usually you should use the [`Stopwatch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) class.

Answer (score 11):

**Timer:**

`Timer()` creates a `Timer` object, that runs your computation after a delay. Since you get the reference to that `Timer` object, you can choose to cancel it before it's fired, by calling `cancel`.

```
Timer t = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print("1 sec later"));
t.cancel(); // nothing will be printed out
```

**Future:**

`Future.delayed` creates a `Future` that runs its computation after a delay. **Internally, it's still using a `Timer` to do that.** It does not expose the timer to you, so you cannot control or cancel it. On the bright side, you get to do your normal Future stuff, like `await` on it.

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1);
print("1 sec later");
```

Comment: I am trying to use `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10 / 2), () {....` and `10/2` does not work for Duration seconds. Kindly suggest what is the solution of it? Thanks.

Comment: I got the solution. It accepts an `int` and `10/2` is a `double`, we can use `10~/2` instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The `timer` runs its job after the given duration, but flutter not waiting for it to complete its execution, it performs below statements.

**Example:**

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      print("Execute this code afer 2 seconds");
    }); 
 print("Other code");
```

**Output:**

```
Other code
Execute this code after 2 seconds
```

So as you can see code below timer will execute first and then the timer will be performed.
Also, Timer can be stopped at any given point before its execution, if we crate the object of it.

```
 Timer timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          print("Execute this code afer 2 seconds");
        }); 
timer.cancel();
```

---

The `future` also runs its job after the given duration, but its return future object means we can use await to get its execution first, and then below statements will be going to execute.

```
 await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          print("Execute this code afer 2 seconds");
        });
        print("My Code");
    print("Other code");
```

**Output:**

```
Execute this code after 2 seconds
Other code
```

The main disadvantage of the `future` is that we can't cancel it in between.

Comment: I am trying to use `Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10 / 2), () {....` and `10/2` does not work for Duration seconds. Kindly suggest what is the solution of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Use Timer if:**

- You want the ability to cancel it. With `Timer.cancel()` you cancel the timer unlike `Future` where you'll have to make use of `CancelableCompleter` to cancel the Future.
- If you don't want to return anything in your callback method.

  Example:

  ```dart
  // Prints 'Hello' after 1s. 
  var timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () => print('Hello'));
  ```

  And in case you decide to cancel it, use:

  ```dart
  timer.cancel();
  ```

---

**Use Future if:**

- Your code can throw errors and you want to catch them. Had you used `Timer` and any uncaught exceptions occurs, the app will exit.
- You want to return something from your callback method.

  Example:

  ```dart
  // Return 'Hello' after 1s and if there is any error, it will be caught. 
  Future
    .delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 'Hello')
    .catchError((err) {});
  ```