# Flutter app gets stuck when using the sleep function

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to make an app that starts to count when a button is pressed but the app keeps getting stuck, once I press on the button it immediately becomes unresponsive

```
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void looping() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      setState(() {
        counter++;
      });
      sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  }

  int counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            looping();
          },
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use future instead of sleep for async. refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449846/how-can-i-sleep-a-dart-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your call to the `sleep` function is inside a for loop that counts from 0 to 99, and the sleep function stops the app for 1 second. The problem seems to be that you are not expecting the app to freeze every time you call to the `sleep` function. But freezing the app it's actually what it is expected to do.

Consider using a `Timer.periodic` instead. Consider this snippet, which is meant to be part of the state of a stateful widget:

```dart
Timer timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => print("Test"));
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

That code will print `"Test"` every second, without freezing the app. I think a similar approach is what you need.

In your case, assuming you want your counter to increment one by one every second, and that you want to stop incrementing it after a certain condition is met, you can cancel the timer inside the periodic function to stop it from incrementing. You need something like:

```dart
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
  if (counter >= 99) {
    timer.cancel();
  } else {
    setState(() => counter++);
  }
});
```

Comment: it worked but it increments the value by 100 every second when it should have been 1.

Comment: You don't need to run the whole loop inside the periodic callback. Consider the snippet I have added to my edited answer, I think it is what you need for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is how sleep works, use it with care, as no asynchronous operations can be processed in a isolate while it is blocked in a sleep call.

To your case consider using `Future.delayed` or `Timer`. You can check their usage here [What is the difference between Future.delayed vs Timer in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61032849/what-is-the-difference-between-future-delayed-vs-timer-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Stream.periodic`.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var counter = 0;
  var streamSubscription; // define the subscription varibale

  void looping() {
  final stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (int _counter){
   setState(()=>counter = _counter); // increments the counter by 1 every second
   if (_counter == 100){
    streamSubscription.cancel(); // cancels the stream when the counter reaches 100
  }});
  streamSubscription = stream.listen((_) => null); // starts listening to the stream
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            looping();
          },
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(counter.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```